# PHP Deprecated: Non-static method > JApplication::redirect() should not be called statically, assuming > $this from incompatible context in

Tags: php, joomla, static, static-methods

I have 2 days with an error 500 on my Joomla 3x Site (www.magic.cr)

> Internal Server Error
>
> The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was
>   unable to complete your request.
>
> Please contact the server administrator at
>   webmaster@magic.kiwitextil.com to inform them of the time this error
>   occurred, and the actions you performed just before this error.
>
> More information about this error may be available in the server error
>   log.
>
> Additionally, a 500 Internal Server Error error was encountered while
>   trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

I found these on my error logs:

> [23-Aug-2016 16:48:00 UTC] PHP Deprecated:  Non-static method
>   JApplication::redirect() should not be called statically, assuming
>   $this from incompatible context in
>   /home/kiwitex/public_html/magic.cr/templates/braink/error.php on line
>   9 [23-Aug-2016 16:48:00 UTC] PHP Notice:  Undefined property:
>   JDocumentError::$_messageQueue in
>   /home/kiwitex/public_html/magic.cr/libraries/legacy/application/application.php
>   on line 376 [23-Aug-2016 16:48:00 UTC] PHP Notice:  Undefined
>   property: JDocumentError::$client in
>   /home/kiwitex/public_html/magic.cr/libraries/legacy/application/application.php
>   on line 394 [23-Aug-2016 16:48:00 UTC] PHP Notice:  Trying to get
>   property of non-object in
>   /home/kiwitex/public_html/magic.cr/libraries/legacy/application/application.php
>   on line 394 [23-Aug-2016 16:48:00 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Call to
>   undefined method JDocumentError::close() in
>   /home/kiwitex/public_html/magic.cr/libraries/legacy/application/application.php
>   on line 409

This is:
public_html/magic.cr/templates/braink/error.php

```css
<?php
defined('_JEXEC') or die;
if (!isset($this->error)) {
 $this->error = JError::raiseWarning(404, JText::_('JERROR_ALERTNOAUTHOR'));
 $this->debug = false; 
}else{
 switch($this->error->getCode()) {
  case "404":
   JApplication::redirect("index.php/404-error"); // replace the redirect URL with your own
   break;
  case "403":
   JApplication::redirect("index.php/404-error"); // replace the redirect URL with your own
   break;
 }
}
```

I can access the administrator: www.magic.cr/administrator

Joomla 3.6.2
PHP Version 5.6.23

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1):

The notice messages are issued because of incorrect usage of the static functions.

Here is the right way to call redirect function.

```
$app = JFactory::getApplication();
$app->redirect(url);
```